# How an image can be transmitted in "chatty" app

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie in iphone app programming and currently I use "chatty" app to communicate with other iPhones. I wonder how I can modify "chatty" in order to send images from one iPhone to another when using chatty app.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Chatty currently sends only strings, so you would need to [extend it to support arbitrary message types](http://xkcd.com/974/). So instead of sending just a string, send type and data, where type is either string or image, and data is, well data.

Look in LocalRoom.m and RemoteRoom.m for this line of code:

```
  BLIPRequest *req = [BLIPRequest requestWithBodyString: message];
```

Chatty uses the [BLIP](https://bytebucket.org/snej/mynetwork/wiki/Documentation/html/index.html) library. To send an image, instead call requestWithData.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The problem with protobuf is that it can only be used, as the examples suggest, with C++, Python, java, any thing but objective C that I am currently using. besides I don't need to send pictures any time I send message, since it is an unnecessary overhead for each message. The most important though, is the fact that if I change the message to a "struct" as you suggested, all transmission and reception functions should be changed and I have no idea where and which functions exactly should change.

Comment: You can use call C functions from your ObjC code, you don't even need any sort of bridge. That being said, there is an ObjC implementation here: http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers

Comment: Thank you for the help. How should I modify my functions and classes? I need to change for example the "writeToOutgoingStream" method in order to accept this new method. I am not even sure whether archive/unarchive methods that packetize and depacketize the data can be used with this new type.  I wonder if you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: I just noticed that it uses its own protocol library, BLIP, so you can  just use that. See my suggestion in the answer on where in the code to modify.

Comment: I didn't find any "blip" or "blipRequest" in either "LocalRoom.m" or "RemoteRoom.m" Are you sure we're talking about the same "chatty"? I am talking about the Chatty I found on "http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/"

Comment: That's funny, I was looking at another version of the same project. The one you indicate has a file Connection.m with the function sendNetworkPacket, which uses NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnArchiver for the serialization. sendNetworkPacket accepts an NSDictionary, so you can put your image data into that parameter when you call it.